# Pspice software - simulation result of boolean circuit not as expected

Tags: pspice

I am trying to verify a boolean expression (AB +AC+AD') for which I constructed a circuit diagram, but the output simulation window shows 2 red lines. I am pretty sure my circuit is correct.

Circuit:

[image]

Simulation results:

[image]

Comment: I tried adding an image - it worked fine.  What error message are you getting when you try to insert a picture?

Comment: Ok I added the image

Comment: What's the boolean expression for the circuit?

Comment: @JRE AB +AC+AD'

Comment: Does the words "Demo" have any relevance on the simulation result?  Some demo software times out, or will allow the examples to run, but fail with any modification, etc.

Comment: Tbh I am new to pspice, and it's the student version I am using, but I don't think it's any relevant here

Comment: Instead of assuming the simulator is wrong or not, do what real engineers do and start **debugging**. Plot inputs and output signal for each gate, does it behave like a NAND gate? Are all gates behaving as they should? If they are then re-create the logic table for the circuit from scratch and compare it to the simulation results.

Comment: Given your expression, why do you only have NAND gates in there? What I mean is, if you want to be able to see what's wrong, wouldn't you make sure you're building this thing so that debugging is easy? Try adding real AND and OR gates.

Comment: Make sure those gates and the clock inputs have the same levels. The gates might be 0-5 V logic, and the clocks might be 0-1 V logic. Or don't use 74 series, try to find out if there are digital primitives, behavioural logic.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen hey actually it's my college experiment to construct the circuit using only NAND gates

Comment: I got the error ..the error was in NAND gate ,I should have used 7400 series instead of 7401 .Can anyone tell what's the difference between 7400 and 7401